# Delete app from android marketplace

Tags: android, google-play

How do i go about removing an app from the android marketplace that i have published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only unpublish an app; you can't actually delete it. If you unpublish it, it won't appear in the Market anymore.

Comment: Thanks i accidentally made it free and had to unpublish it, make a new one with a new package name and then publish it again as a paid app